# How to get updateProfile() working in firebase?

Tags: flutter

I am trying create an app using Firebase. But when I use updateProfile(), I get this error. The method 'updateProfile' isn't defined for the type 'Future'.

```
Future  updateProfilePic(picUrl) {
    var userInfo = new UserUpdateInfo();
    userInfo.photoUrl = picUrl;
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    user.updateProfile(userInfo).then((val) {
      FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
        Firestore.instance
            .collection('/Recycling Points')
            .where('uid', isEqualTo: user.uid)
            .getDocuments()
            .then((docs) {
          Firestore.instance
              .document('/Recycling Points/${docs.documents[0].documentID}')
              .updateData({'image': picUrl}).then((value){
                print ('uploaded');
          });
        });
      }).catchError((e) {
        print(e);
      });
    });
  }
```

**EDIT:**
This is the full code.

Import package

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:smartbin/models/recycle.dart';
import 'package:smartbin/models/user.dart';
```

Database Service

```
class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;
  DatabaseService({this.uid});
```

Collection reference

```
  final CollectionReference recyclepointsCollection =
      Firestore.instance.collection('Recycle Points');

  Future updateUserData(String name, String email, String image,
      int organicWaste, int nonOrganicWaste, int recycleWaste) async {
    return await recyclepointsCollection.document(uid).setData({
      'name': name,
      'email': email,
      'image': image,
      'Organic Waste ': organicWaste,
      'Non Organic Waste': nonOrganicWaste,
      'Recycling Waste ': recycleWaste,
    });
  }
```

recycle points list from snapshot

```
  List<Recycle> _recycleListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      return Recycle(
          name: doc.data['name'] ?? '',
          email: doc.data['email'] ?? '',
          image: doc.data['image'] ?? '',
          organicWaste: doc.data['organicWaste'] ?? 0,
          nonOrganicWaste: doc.data['nonOrganicWaste'] ?? 0,
          recycleWaste: doc.data['recycleWaste'] ?? 0);
    }).toList();
  }
```

Update profile pic code

```
void  updateProfilePic(picUrl) {
    var userInfo = new UserUpdateInfo();
    userInfo.photoUrl = picUrl;
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    user.updateProfile(userInfo).then((val) {
      FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
        Firestore.instance
            .collection('/Recycling Points')
            .where('uid', isEqualTo: user.uid)
            .getDocuments()
            .then((docs) {
          Firestore.instance
              .document('/Recycling Points/${docs.documents[0].documentID}')
              .updateData({'image': picUrl}).then((value){
            print ('uploaded');
          });
        });
      }).catchError((e) {
        print(e);
      });
    });
  }
```

User data from snapshot

```
  UserData _userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return UserData(
        uid: uid,
        name: snapshot.data['name'],
        email: snapshot.data['email'],
        image: snapshot.data['image'],
        organicWaste: snapshot.data['organicWaste'],
        nonOrganicWaste: snapshot.data['nonOrganicWaste'],
        recycleWaste: snapshot.data['recycleWaste']);
  }
```

get recyclepoints stream

```
  Stream<List<Recycle>> get recyclePoints {
    return recyclepointsCollection.snapshots().map(_recycleListFromSnapshot);
  }
```

get user doc stream

```
  Stream<UserData> get userData {
    return recyclepointsCollection
        .document(uid)
        .snapshots()
        .map(_userDataFromSnapshot);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

```
void updateProfilePic(picUrl) {
    var userInfo = new UserUpdateInfo();
    userInfo.photoUrl = picUrl;
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    user.updateProfile(userInfo).then((val) {
      FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
        Firestore.instance
            .collection('/Recycling Points')
            .where('uid', isEqualTo: user.uid)
            .getDocuments()
            .then((docs) {
          Firestore.instance
              .document('/Recycling Points/${docs.documents[0].documentID}')
              .updateData({'image': picUrl}).then((value){
                print ('uploaded');
          });
        });
      }).catchError((e) {
        print(e);
      });
    });
  }
```

Change from Future to void method.

Comment: Tried it . Still this error shows up. `The method 'updateProfile' isn't defined for the type 'Future'.`

Comment: Can you share the full code on how you used 'updateProfile'

Comment: If error still shows up that "The method 'updateProfile' isn't defined for the type 'Future'." after changing "Future" to "void".

Comment: If you did a hot reload; try re-starting the app

Comment: I did that. And I still get an error. `44:10: Error: The method 'updateProfile' isn't defined for the class 'Future<FirebaseUser>'.
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
 - 'FirebaseUser' is from 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' ('/C:/Users/Predator/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.16.1/lib/firebase_auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'updateProfile'.
    user.updateProfile(userInfo).then((val) {`
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this code solves your problem or not

```
void updateProfilePic(picUrl) async {
        var userInfo = new UserUpdateInfo();
        userInfo.photoUrl = picUrl;
        final user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
        user.updateProfile(userInfo).then((val) {
          FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
            Firestore.instance
                .collection('/Recycling Points')
                .where('uid', isEqualTo: user.uid)
                .getDocuments()
                .then((docs) {
              Firestore.instance
                  .document('/Recycling Points/${docs.documents[0].documentID}')
                  .updateData({'image': picUrl}).then((value){
                    print ('uploaded');
              });
            });
          }).catchError((e) {
            print(e);
          });
        });
      }
```

Comment: No it doesn''t work. Got same error. `Error: The method 'updateProfile' isn't defined for the class 'Future<FirebaseUser>'.
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
 - 'FirebaseUser' is from 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart'`